# Panning MATLAB figure by code

Tags: matlab, visualization

I want to do a series of figures and automatically alter parameters as for e.g. **`pan`**. Is there a way to pan a figure on the x- or y- axis without using the interactive, mouse-based mode?

---

The (automatic generated) result could look like this e.g. - shifted in negative x-axis direction:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This question is somewhat ambiguous. Do you mean panning in figure coordinate system (2D) or in axes coordinate system (2D or 3D)? The interactive `pan` acts differently depending on the axes dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this like this

```
a=xlim; %get the initial axes limits
xlim(a-0.5); %move the pan 0.5 unit to the right
```

you can do this for ylim, zlim as well